# SharePoint 2016 Content Search Images

Tags: search, content

I'm trying to add a Content Search web part to my SharePoint site which will show the images of all libraries within the current site. Although I did succeed in showing the images as thumbnails, the associated link directs to the "back-end" (i.e. it opens the Form behind it) rather than linking to the image directly. Is there a workaround?

Apologies for the "simple" explanation, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit webpart and in properties(under Property Mappings) change `Link URL` to `Picture URL` instead `Path`

placeholder picture

[image]

Comment: It does not show Property Mappings in my sidebar of options. How do I enable this?